# get particular column value

Tags: php, arrays

i want take the particular column all value in multidimensional array...

i need to get the value of or column ("rose","daisy","orchid")...

how do get?

is there any predefined function?
because in my array have 1000 record, so loop will continue to run 1000 times, program will slow, so...

Comment: Please provide the full array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$shop = array( array("rose", 1.25 , 15),
               array("daisy", 0.75 , 25),
               array("orchid", 1.15 , 7)
          );

echo $shop[0][0]." costs ".$shop[0][1]." and you get ".$shop[0][2]."\n";
echo $shop[1][0]." costs ".$shop[1][1]." and you get ".$shop[1][2]."\n";
echo $shop[2][0]." costs ".$shop[2][1]." and you get ".$shop[2][2]."\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through each array in the array, choosing only one key (Sorry if that sounds a bit confusing, here's what I mean):

```
$flowers = array();
$flowers[] = array('type'=>'rose', 'color'=>'red');
$flowers[] = array('type'=>'daisy', 'color'=>'white');
$flowers[] = array('type'=>'orchid', 'color'=>'pink');

foreach ($flowers as $flower) {
    echo $flower['type'];
}
```

This will print out whatever's in column 'type' for each flower.

Comment: is there any predefined function?
because in my array have 1000 record, so loop will continue to run 1000 times, program will slow that's why i asked...